# Login redirect is not working

Tags: redirect, login

I am currently trying to make it so when I have logged in on my website as a user it redirects to a certain page.

However it is not working.

I have tried adding the following redirect in the configuration file however no luck:

```
'postLoginRedirect' => 'profile/test'
```

Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the redirect to happen after the user logs in via a front-end form, or via the `/admin/login` form? If it's the latter, you need to use `postCpLoginRedirect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set a path in the actual form as well.

`<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/some/url">`

Just drop this field in the login form, assuming this is what you're using.

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/login-form

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys. I solved it.
The issue was that I was logging in as the admin not an ordinary user.